# GR Action and Ashtekar Connection

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, curvature, action

Palatini action $S_{Pal}$ is (assuming Cosmological constant $\Lambda=0)$:
$$ S_{Pal}[e,\omega]=\int  e\wedge e\wedge R[\omega].$$

Motion equations (varying this action) gives us Einstein Equation and
$$ d_\omega (e\wedge e)=0 \implies d_\omega e=0$$
which is the same to say connection $\omega$ is torsion-free.

**Here enters my doubt**: in order to work with LQG is quite-necessary to introduce Ashtekar connection (which has torsion)
$$A^i_a=\Gamma^i_a +\gamma K^i_a. $$
I also know that is commum nowadays to just start with Holst action
$$S_H[e,\omega]=\int \left(\star+\frac{1}{\gamma}\right) e\wedge e\wedge R[\omega].$$
Fist time I thought that varying $S_H$ with respect to $\omega$ it should gives Ashtekar connection, but apparently I was wrong and actually it gives Levi-Civita connection, same as Palatini action. Thus, even with $\gamma$ appearing in both action and ashtekar connection expression, they seems to be not related (a priori)

There's some action $S_A$ such that $\delta S_A$ gives us Ashtekar connection?

What is the physical meaning that I should have about some connection $\omega$ be the extremum of $\delta_\omega S$ variation? Comparing with classical action, motion equation are those patch (on configuration space) that minimazes the energy. Is it ok to keep this interpretation while working with actions with $\omega$ being the variable?